# What is the problem with putting brackets("(") in a printf code

Tags: c, printf

I've just started C-Programming and have a question on the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int num1, num2, num3;
    int result;

        printf("(num1 - num2) x (num2 + num3) x (num3 % num1) \n");
    printf("Insert 3 numbers: ");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &num1, &num2, &num3);

    result = (num1 - num2) * (num2 + num3) * (num3 % num1);
    printf("Answer: %d ", result);
    return 0;
}
```

An Error occurs whenever I put the following single line of code:

```
  printf("(num1 - num2) x (num2 + num3) x (num3 % num1) \n");
```

The reason I put this in was because I wanted to print this equation, but an error occurs whenever I put this in. The error message seems to say that there is a problem in the usage of brackets, but I don't get why putting brackets becomes a problem.

I expect the output to be,

```
  (num1 - num2) x (num2 + num3) x (num3 % num1)
  Insert 3 numbers:
```

But the Following Error occurs:

"Debug Assertion Failed"

...

Expression: "("'n' format specifier disabled",')

Comment: Put `%%` instead of `%` in your format string.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not about the parenthesis, it's about the `%`. For `printf()` format string, `%` character has a special meaning.

From `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.1

> [...] The format is composed of zero or more directives: ordinary multibyte
>   characters **(not %)**, which are copied unchanged to the output stream; **and conversion
>   specifications,** each of which results in fetching zero or more subsequent arguments,
>   converting them, if applicable, according to the corresponding conversion specifier, and
>   then writing the result to the output stream.

and

> Each conversion specification is introduced by the character `%`. [...]

So, to print a `%` character itself, you need to put another `%` as the conversion specifier. From the list of conversion specifiers, (paragraph 8 in the same spec)

> `%`    A `%` character is written. No argument is converted. The complete
>   conversion specification shall be `%%`.